# function calling sequence disturbed due to exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

It may sound very basic but I am stuck in a situation where the function calling sequence is being disturbed due to exception even after exception handling.

I have the following situation in my windows form project (C#) (dummy code only):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
       {
           BAL objBAL = new BAL();

           objBAL.BL_Function1();
           objBAL.BL_Function2();
           objBAL.BL_Function3();
           objBAL.BL_Function4();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

the above functions are called from the business logic(BL) class which further has function callings of various functions of Data Access Layer (DAL) class.

Now the problem is whenever exception comes in any of the above functions, let's say `BL_Function3()`, it resets the calling to `BL_Function1()` which leaves `BL_Function4()` uncalled, which is not desirable.

My question is:

**Is there any way to persists the calling sequence, i.e., if exception occurs at BL_Function2(), it should go ahead and call BL_Function3() and BL_Function4(), and then return back to BL_Function1() in the next timer_tick ?**

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want wrap *each* `objBAL.BL_FunctionN();` into `try ... catch...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap *each* method into `try..catch`:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //TODO: you may want to stop timer here... 

    BAL objBAL = new BAL();

    try {
        objBAL.BL_Function1();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { //TODO: catch more specific exception (not Exception)
        // If BL_Function1() fails, show message...
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    } 

    // ...and go ahead
    try {
        objBAL.BL_Function2();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    } 

    try {
        objBAL.BL_Function3();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    } 

    try {
        objBAL.BL_Function4();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    } 

    //...and restart the timer here 
}
```

**Edit:** please note, that the timer keep on ticking when `MessageBox` is on the screen. You may want to stop the timer for a while and then restart it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Stop the timer until execution is complete
  timer1.Enabled = false;

  try {
    //Put all the executions here 
    ...
  }
  finally {
    // execution is complete (with or without exceptions), let's restart the timer
    timer1.Enabled = true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: the position is still the same.. the exception came at BL_Function2() and function calling is reset to BL_Function1()

Comment: @DeepakVerma: please note, that timer keep on ticking when `MessageBox` is on the screen. You, probably, want either write message to some kind of log or stop the timer for a while

Comment: You could spawn a thread to display the MessageBox so you dont block.

Comment: I am writing the exception to a log in database in my project. The above MessageBox is there just for illustration

Comment: @DeepakVerma: be careful with writing: you can have yet *another exception* in the process which you should catch as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to make it cleaner

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objBAL = new BAL();
    Action[] functions = { objBAL.BL_Function1, objBAL.BL_Function2, objBAL.BL_Function3, objBAL.BL_Function3 };

    foreach (var fun in functions)
    {
        var funCopy = fun;

        try
        {
            funCopy ();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: doesn't work... the var fun has the calling value as "objBAL.BL_Function1" after exception appears at "objBAL.BL_Function2"

Comment: right there is a bug in .NET for closure variables. The answer is to make a copy. I will update the code